# Provide a link to Stack Exchange API in the footer

Tags: feature-request, api, stackapps, footer

Currently, getting to the API page is a two- (or more) step process. The user has to first visit [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) and in the rightmost column; there are links for API documentations, etc.

I think it'd be easier and more useful if the API is also listed in the footer just like [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE) is provided.

Something like:

[image: Something like]

Comment: How many use the API doc? Why a link on the main page for so few users?

Comment: @juergend It'll be used if people are made aware about this. Just like Data Explorer.

Comment: @hjpotter92 debatable. I definitely didn't learn about data.SE from the footer, nor would I have found the API by looking at the footer. In fact, I can't really think of a time I've used the footer, other than to copy-paste the license that's in use.

Answer (score 4):

While this link was added some time ago (and hidden behind "Other", I think) with the [new footer updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372007/reducing-the-weight-of-our-footer) it is now out and easy to see:

[image: "API" link listed under the heading "STACK EXCHANGE NETWORK" as one of only a few in its column]